# Webpack -p slow build "[BABEL]" Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "file.jsx" as it exceeds the max of "500KB"

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, uglifyjs

While running `webpack -p` this BABEL note is thrown. The build is notoriously slow(takes almost 2 minutes), and specifically hangs at this point(for almost a minute).

The file itself is actually a Leaflet.js dataset of map tiles, saved in a variable and imported into another component. It's almost 16000 lines long.

How can I get around this warning/error, and possibly decrease my `webpack -p` build time? This file never changes at all, it's completely static. Is there a better way to load and bundle it?

Here's a stacktrace from the first part where it definitely hangs, though not related to the above warning:

```
[ERROR] loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
[ERROR] parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
[INFO] Hash: 3630895d5243d91f70f9
[INFO] Version: webpack 2.2.1
[INFO] Time: 112723ms
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After searching and trying several things, the following one worked. I included `exclude: /node_modules/` 
on my loader like this:

```
rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] }
    ]
```

I found the above information in [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6041) thread.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this section into your .babelrc file:

```js
{
  "env": {
    "development" : {
      "compact": false
    }
  },
  ...
}
```